# Symfony2: Get Service Inside Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to call service inside entity

I need entity Manager inside entity so I can able to get custom result with repository functions.

I am thinking about inject ContainerInterface inside my entity like this.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyEntity
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getEntityManager(){
        return $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    }
}
```

But I think this is not right way to do that and it take more code I mean I have to do this for all entity where I need entity Manager

Is there any good solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can but you shouldn't do it anyway. The entities are meant to be really simple...

> need entity Manager inside entity so i can able to get custom result with repository functions

What do you want to do exactly, there must be a different solution...

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, dependency injection is definitely the wrong way to go.

Use either Custom Entity Repositories (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) for more complex queries or use a specific service where you can implement your custom result if more complexity is needed (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services)